# How to pass the source term when solving ODE using odeint

Tags: python, ode

Differential equation of forced harmonic oscillator is given as Mx''+Lx'+(w^2)x=F(t). Here F(t) is a source term. To solve this problem I wrote a code where I define the differential equation in a function 'diff'. I wrote another function 'generate_pulse' that gives the F(t).

Then I use 'odeint', which solves the differential equation by calling the 'diff' function along with other parameters. Now I don't get any error message if I put F=0 inside the 'diff' function (i.e., ignore any F(t) term). Please have a look inside the 'diff' function:

```
F=0         #No error detected if I put F=0 here. Comment out this line to see the error
```

Once I keep the F(t), I get an error message 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.'

How to solve the problem?

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import itertools



def diff(y, t,param):
    M=param[0]
    L=param[1]
    w2=param[2]
    F=param[3]
    F=0         #No error detected if I put F=0 here. Comment out this line to see the error
    x,v = y
    dydt = [v, (F-L*v - w2*x)/M]
    return dydt


def generate_pulse(t,Amp,init_delay,rtime,PW):


        L=len(t)
        t0=t[0:math.ceil(init_delay*L/100)]  
        t1=t[len(t0):len(t0)+math.ceil(rtime*L/100)]
        t2=t[len(t0)+len(t1):len(t0)+len(t1)+math.ceil(PW*L/100)]
        t3=t[len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2):len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+2*math.ceil(rtime*L/100)]
        t4=t[len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+len(t3):len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+len(t3)+math.ceil(PW*L/100)]
        t5=t[len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+len(t3)+len(t4):len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+len(t3)+len(t4)+math.ceil(rtime*L/100)]
        t6=t[len(t0)+len(t1)+len(t2)+len(t3)+len(t4)+len(t5):]

        s0=0*t0

        s1=(Amp/(t1[-1]-t1[0]))*(t1-t1[0])
        s2=np.full((1,len(t2)),Amp)
        s2=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s2))  #The 'tuple' is converted into array

        s3=-Amp/(t1[-1]-t1[0])*(t3-t3[0])+Amp

        s4=np.full((1,len(t4)),-Amp)
        s4=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s4))  #The 'tuple' is converted into array

        s5=(Amp/(t5[-1]-t5[0]))*(t5-t5[0])-Amp
        s6=np.full((1,len(t6)),0)
        s6=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s6))  #The 'tuple' is converted into array

        s=[s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6]
        s=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s))
        return s

###############################################################################
#                      Main code from here

t = np.linspace(0, 30, 200)
y0 = [- 10, 0.0]


M=5
L = 1
w2 = 15.0

Amp=5
init_delay=10
rtime=10
PW=10

F=generate_pulse(t,Amp,init_delay,rtime,PW)


Param=([M,L,w2,F],)   #Making the 'Param' a tuple. Because args of odeint takes tuple as argument. 


sol = odeint(diff, y0, t, args=Param)


plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='x(t)')
plt.plot(t,F,'g',label='Force(t)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the value of `F` that you pass is the array that you generated.

Use the interpolation functions of numpy or scipy to make an actual function out of the arrays. Then evaluate that function at time `t`. Or directly implement the forcing term as a piecewise defined function of the scalar `t`.

Also note that the list of sampling times you give in `t` to `odeint` has (almost) nothing to do with the times at which `odeint` calls the ODE function `diff`. If you want to control that you would have to implement your own fixed-step method, probably not Runge-Kutta but some multi-step method.